# KnockoutJS bind radio checkbox labels and elements

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have radio checkboxes with labels that contain class name such as 'product, product type, and renewal date'. I'm trying to bind these to a result table. Where one column will be the product, another will be product type and the other a renewal date.

All that I can seem to extract at the moment is just the value of the input. But how do I extract the html of the label and put that in a table cell?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAVGrY

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checked: selectedProduct">
<label><strong><span data-bind="product">Product A</span></strong> - <span data-bind="productType" class="productType">Product A Type</span> <span class="renewalDate">Due on <strong><span data-bind="renewalDate">18-07-17</span></strong></span></label>
  </li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" data-bind="checked: selectedProduct">
<label><span class="product"><strong>Product B</strong></span> - <span class="productType">Product B Type</span> <span class="renewalDate">Due on <strong>12-06-17</strong></span></label>
</li>       
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" data-bind="checked: selectedProduct">
<label><span class="product"><strong>Product C</strong></span> - <span class="productType">Product C Type</span> <span class="renewalDate">Due on <strong>18-07-17</strong></span></label>
</li>
</ul>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td data-bind="text: displayedProduct"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var viewModel= function () {

 var self = this;

self.selectedProduct = ko.observableArray();
self.displayedProduct = ko.computed(function() {
  var str = "";
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedProduct(), function(item) {
  str += item + " ";                                
});         
return str;
});
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: You should have a template for displaying you desired details instead of data-bind="text: displayedProduct" and on selection pass the required data of the selected item to the template

Comment: but how do I get the label data off the selected radio checkbox?

Comment: Normally I used to have a Product model which contains the name, type, renewal data etc. I would create an array of Products so that I can perform a loop to display the checkboxes to avoid hardcoding the details (name, type, data in this case). Now when a checkbox is selected, you could get the entire Product object instead of plain text/id. Pass this selected product object to the template and there you go...

Comment: thanks i'll give that a go.

Comment: Sure. Try it out and let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: Ok so it has to be hard coded. Does that mean I just have to find the hard coded products and put them into an object?

Comment: that should do. Idea is, in future if you would like to get the product list from a service rather than hard coding in html, the changes will be minimum. Even if you don't have a service, just think about the effort between replicating the html for new products vs adding new product into product array. In your case, you will be having array of 3 products and in html you have to foreach the array to render the li tags. The checked: will be bound to the entire product object and you have to pass this object to the template.

Comment: You can have a template which renders li tag with required details from product object and reuse it in foreach as well

Comment: When I add a checked: to the product object, all the product check boxes become checked even if I only clicked one?

Comment: I have created a codepen for you. To continue this discussion further, I'll add it as answer and lets dicuss there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a viewmodel for product with name, date, value, type and isSelected
- Create a array of products and render the checkboxes instead of hardcoded li's
- You can use the same template for rendering li as well as to show the selected items

Find the fiddle here - http://codepen.io/AnonymousDeveloper/pen/bZyLBN

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li data-bind="foreach: products">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected, value: name"/>

<span data-bind="template: { name: 'product-template', data: $data }"></span>

  </li>

</ul>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      Selected Items<br/>
      <span data-bind="foreach: products">
        <span data-bind="if: isSelected">
        <span data-bind="template: { name: 'product-template', data: $data }"></span>
          <br/>
        </span>
      </span>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="product-template">

    <label><strong><span data-bind="text:name"></span></strong> - <span data-bind="text:productType" class="productType"></span> <span class="renewalDate">Due on <strong><span data-bind="text:renewalDate"></span></strong></span></label>     

</script>
```

JS

```
var viewModel= function () {

  var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray();

  self.products.push(new product(1, 'Product A', '18-07-17','Product A Type'));
  self.products.push(new product(2, 'Product B', '18-08-17','Product B Type'));
  self.products.push(new product(3, 'Product C', '18-10-17','Product C Type'));  

};

var product = function(value,name, date, type) {
  var self = this;
  self.value = value;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.renewalDate = ko.observable(date);
  self.productType = ko.observable(type);
  self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for that.

Comment: Yes thanks! I did have an issue which i removed from stackoverflow (in case you saw it) but it was just a typo from me. But i'm able to get it working on my end. Just fiddling now trying to get a separate ID for each of the products.

Comment: @Pizdets - Okay, please mark as answer if this helped.

Comment: no problem. Says it's recorded since i'm under 15 rep.

Comment: @Pizdets - May be you tried voting up. I think there should be an option to mark this as answer.

Comment: @Pizdets - Thanks mate. Btw, you could make a minor change in the product model in my sample; only the property "isSelected" should be observable others can be simple properties as there isnt a change happening to those properties which we should keep an eye on.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to construct your UI via knockout by using separate viewmodels and `foreach` or `template` bindings, you could use the `checkedValue` binding.

This binding lets you specify which value you want to store when the checkbox is checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedProduct, 
                                  checkedValue: 'Product A'">
```

In your example:

```js
var viewModel= function () {

 var self = this;

self.selectedProduct = ko.observableArray();
self.displayedProduct = ko.computed(function() {
  var str = "";
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedProduct(), function(item) {
  str += item + " ";                                
});         
return str;
});
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-bind="checked: selectedProduct, checkedValue: 'Product A'">
<label><strong><span data-bind="product">Product A</span></strong> - <span data-bind="productType" class="productType">Product A Type</span> <span class="renewalDate">Due on <strong><span data-bind="renewalDate">18-07-17</span></strong></span></label>
  </li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" data-bind="checked: selectedProduct, checkedValue: 'Product B'">
<label><span class="product"><strong>Product B</strong></span> - <span class="productType">Product B Type</span> <span class="renewalDate">Due on <strong>12-06-17</strong></span></label>
</li>       
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" data-bind="checked: selectedProduct, checkedValue: 'Product C'">
<label><span class="product"><strong>Product C</strong></span> - <span class="productType">Product C Type</span> <span class="renewalDate">Due on <strong>18-07-17</strong></span></label>
</li>
</ul>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td data-bind="text: displayedProduct"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```